# How many times is Blake2b called with Argon2?

Tags: argon2, blake2

How many times is *Blake2b* called with *Argon2*?

Say `argon2 thisissomesalt -d -k 1048576 -p 4 -t 20`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I think `-k 1048576` means $1048576 \times 1024 = 1073741824$ bytes.
- I think *BlaMka* (modified *Blake2b*) has a block size of $512$ bytes in *Argon2*.
- I think `-t 20` means repeat the work on the entire $1073741824$ bytes memory pad for $20$ times.

So, I think, the total number of times *BlaMka* is called is:

$$
20\frac{1073741824}{512} = 41,943,040
$$